# What figures does the Chaos;Head protagonist have on his shelf?

Tags: chaos-head

In the Chaos;Head Visual Novel, the protaganist's room has lots of anime merchandise scattered around. Behind his PC he has a large set of shelves with anime characters on them:

[image]
[image]
Some gameplay of this scene can be seen on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/BlpA2NV2AXQ?t=1250)

I've also seen this image online, so perhaps one is changed in a remake or a spinoff or a different scene or something?

[image]

This one has figurines of [Seira](http://chaoshead2.wikia.com/wiki/Seira_Orgel), an in-game fantasy anime character, and the other figures seem fairly generic — so I presume they're not from other shows.

The first image's characters are much more distinctive though and I can instantly recognise Saber from Fate/stay night.

**What are the other series represented here?**

Comment: A lot of them are from Fate/Stay Night, like Rider and Rin. I also see Tsukihime's Arcueid, too.

Comment: I also recognize some characters are from Da Capo.

Comment: YouTube link is dead :( Also, the last image is from *Chaos;Head NOAH* (console version), [which was adapted from the anime's scene (the figurines only)](http://dengekionline.com/elem/000/000/139/139957/). Anyway, from [Japanese Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHAOS;HEAD#.E4.B8.BB.E4.BA.BA.E5.85.AC) some of the figurines are related to Nitro+ games (in NOAH,   some are taken from their collaboration games).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Chaos;Head (PC Version)

- **Top**: Hazuki (*Demonbane*), Another Blood (*Demonbane*), Al Azif (*Demonbane*), Ruri Hadou (*Demonbane*, Zanmataisei ver), Ruri Hadou (*Demonbane*, Kishin Hishou ver), Ignis (*Jingai Makyou*), Franco Il Nero (*Satsuriku no Jango*), Alfie (*Satsuriku no Jango*), Ignis (*Jingai Makyou*), ???, Donne Anonime (*Satsuriku no Jango*), Mahiro Sendou (*Memories Off 5: Togireta Film*), ???, Euretta (*Eternal Fantasy*), ???
- **Middle**: Rebecca (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), ???, Rin Tohsaka (*Fate/stay night*), ???, ???, Yume Asakura (*Da Capo II*), Otome Asakura (*Da Capo II*), Anna (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), Perla (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), ???, Ruri Hadou (*Demonbane*, Zanmataisei ver), Saber (*Fate/stay night*), Leica Crusade (*Demonbane*), Franco Il Nero (*Satsuriku no Jango*)
- **Bottom**: ???, Mahiro Sendou (Memories Off 5: Togireta Film), Euretta (Eternal Fantasy), Donne Anonime (*Satsuriku no Jango*), Otome Asakura (*Da Capo II*), Anna (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), ???, Alfie (*Satsuriku no Jango*), ???, Al Azif (*Demonbane*, nendoroid), Jessica (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), Leica Crusade (*Demonbane*), Rider (*Fate/stay night*), ???, Anna (*Gekkou no Carnevale*), Arcueid Brunestud (*Tsukihime*), Lunaria (*Gekkou no Carnevale*)
- **Desk Shelf**: Noel (*Gekkou no Carnavale*), Lunaria (*Gekkou no Carnavale*)

### Summary

- Nitro+

  - *Demonbane*

    - Al Azif
    - Ruri Hadou
    - Leica Crusade
    - Hazuki
    - Another Blood
  - *Jingai Makyou*

    - Ignis
  - *Satsuriko no Jango*

    - Franco Il Nero
    - Donne Anonime
    - Alfie
  - *Gekkou no Carneval*

    - Anna
    - Lunaria
    - Noel
    - Rebecca
    - Perla
- TYPE-MOON

  - *Tsukihime*

    - Arcueid Brunestud
  - *Fate/stay night*

    - Saber
    - Rin Tohsaka
    - Rider
- Circus

  - *Da Capo II*

    - Otome Asakura
    - Yume Asakura
  - *Eternal Fantasy*

    - Euretta
- KID

  - *Memories Off 5: Togireta Film*

    - Mahiro Sendou

## Chaos;Head NOAH (Console Version)

- **Top**: Rider (*Fate/stay night*), ...
- **Middle**: Seira Orgel (*Chaos;Head*), ...
- **Bottom**: Saber (*Fate/stay night*), ...
- **Desk Shelf**: ...

### Summary

- Nitro+

  - *Chaos;Head*

    - Seira Orgel
- TYPE-MOON

  - *Fate/stay night*

    - Saber
    - Rider

Comment: I couldn't finish it, and it has taken days to research this. So, I decided to make it community wiki. Feel free to update and fill-in the rest...